# http-client call a function on response arrival

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

let's say I have a service that is sending a post request to my API, and as soon as the response has arrived, I'd like a custom function to be executed as part of the process.

```
public signin(){
  return this.http.post<any>(`${env.API_URL}/user/signin`, { username: user.username, password: user.password }).toPromise();
}
```

I have tried using the pipe operator, but for some reason it wasn't sending errors to the returned promise.

```
public signin(){
  return this.http.post<any>(`${env.API_URL}/user/signin`, { username: user.username, password: user.password }).pipe(
    tap(
      data => this.customFunction(data),
      error => error
    )
  ).toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the following code:

```
public signin() {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${env.API_URL}/user/signin`, { username: user.username, password: user.password })
  .toPromise()
  .then((data) => {
    this.customFunction(data)
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Then just define a handle error function, or use a lambda function just like with data if you prefer

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use code like this:

```
getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl).pipe(
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

You could then add your custom function in the tap.

So your code would look more like this:

```
public signin() {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${env.API_URL}/user/signin`, { username: user.username, password: user.password }).pipe(
    tap(data => this.customFunction(data)),
    catchError(error => console.log(error))
  );
}
```